# Visa approved but unable to use due to loan problems

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, study

One of my friends had recently applied for a visa and had got approved, but due to loan problems he is unable to use his Visa right now and leave for Germany, will it be a problem for his future Student Visa processes even if he applies for a new country other than Germany. Please advise he's really worried.

Comment: Unused visas are not at all a problem for future visas (source:personal experience)

Comment: "is unable to use his Visa right now and leave for Germany".His nationality is Indian and no he's never been to Germany..

Comment: These kind of questions can not have a single real answer. It depends from case to case, embassy to embassy, time to time.. Hence, I am voting to close.

Comment: German embassy ,since he did not get his loan approved for his tution fees in the university but his Visa got approved and he was unable to use it....

Comment: Not using an issued visa is no problem at all. He won't get a refund, though. His visa is paid for and for sure he doesn't overstay on it ;-), so he will get any future visa for Germany approved if the other factors are the same. There is no field "did you apply for a visa and then didn't use it", only a field "did you apply for a visa and were rejected"...

Comment: I heard of an occasion when a US consul refused a visa on the grounds that the previous visa wasn't used without a reasonable cause.

Comment: I voted to leave it open because even though it is broad, there is no apparent way to narrow it.

Comment: I haven't used my Schengen visa once and no questions asked when I applied again and got one.

Comment: But sir he is from a non EU country and it was a student Schengen visa so he's worried ...actually sme people are misleading him so i wanted to make sure there's no problem with it ....or even if there is how to effectively face and overcome it since it is not a criminal offence ...

Answer (score 5):

The generic name for this type of situation is 'Change of Circumstances'.  They do not count against the person if they are properly declared and not abused.

If your friend wants to play it *strictly by the book*, you can advise your friend to file a variance with the German consulate that issued the visa, and explain that the loan did not come through as planned and that they will not have the funds to sustain themselves. The German consulate will revoke the visa without prejudice and your friend's credibility will be enhanced the next time they apply for something.

On the other hand, if your friends arrives in Germany, they will be examined to assure that they have the necessary funds to support themselves and to pay for their courses AND to finally return to their home country. If they are unable to satisfy the border official that they have the means, then they will be vulnerable. Moreover, they will need to think up a convincing reason why they travelled knowing that they could not accomplish the purpose of their visa.

Comment: That... doesn't make sense.  How could German immigration possibly know about a loan refusal in India?  If they show up at the border with a valid visa, they'll (most likely) get in.  If they never use the visa, no harm done.

Comment: @jpatokal, please see Regulation 562/2006, particularly Article 7.  Or alternatively, provide another answer :)

Comment: I'm asking about practice, not theory here. *How could German immigration possibly know about a loan refusal in India?*

Comment: @jpatokal, why do they need to know about it?

Comment: What are you referring to with "if they show up at the border and DO NOT declare the change of circumstances, then there's a problem" then?

Comment: @jpatokal, excellent point!  I have made an edit.

Comment: So that he already declared it to the embassy that due to loan not getting through he couldn't fund himself and so he couldn't go for this intake ...but since he has applied for a private language school over there ,they are threatening him that they will mail foreign affairs that student is not serious and that he applied without arranging proper funds and that he cannot apply for a Student visa at all ...so he's really really worried ...

Comment: @Dinesh If the school is threatening to contact the authorities, tell them to take a hike.

Comment: @gayotFow Sir u mean he can just turn a deaf ear to that ?